# Trim Segment in LMMS

Tags: learning, dj

I have used a simple DAW before and there was a trim function where I placed the timeline where I wished to cut it and pushed a button. Is there anything like this in LMMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no.

The [LMMS manual](https://lmms.io/pdf/lmms-manual-0.4.12.pdf) says on page 43

> Note that an entire element always gets deleted as a single unit (you cannot selectively
>   snip away parts of an element – You will have to edit the contents of the element, as
>   described below.).

and on page 47

> LMMS cannot edit this track at all (e.g. trimming/slicing, or scaling it to fit with the bars in
>   your music). You have to edit the track beforehand, using an audio editor (e.g. Audacity).